# GraphQL Relay Mutation Config RANGE_ADD's parentName for connections

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I have a page that uses GraphQL Relay connection which fetches `drafts`.

```json
query {
    connections {
        drafts(first: 10) {
            edges {
                node {
                    ... on Draft {
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this page, I also create draft through `CreateDraftMutation`.

```json
mutation {
    createDraft(input: {
        clientMutationId: "1"
        content: "content"
    }) {
        draft {
            id
            content
        }
    }
}
```

After this mutation, I want Relay to add the created draft into its store. The best candidate for mutation config is RANGE_ADD, which is documented as following:

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html

> RANGE_ADD 
>   Given a parent, a connection, and the name of the newly created edge in the response payload Relay will add the node to the store and attach it to the connection according to the range behavior specified.
>
> Arguments
>
> parentName: string
>   The field name in the response that represents the parent of the connection
>
> parentID: string
>   The DataID of the parent node that contains the connection
>
> connectionName: string
>   The field name in the response that represents the connection
>
> edgeName: string
>   The field name in the response that represents the newly created edge
>
> rangeBehaviors: {[call: string]: GraphQLMutatorConstants.RANGE_OPERATIONS}
>
> A map between printed, dot-separated GraphQL calls in alphabetical order, and the behavior we want Relay to exhibit when adding the new edge to connections under the influence of those calls. Behaviors can be one of 'append', 'ignore', 'prepend', 'refetch', or 'remove'.

The example from the documentation goes as the following:

```js
class IntroduceShipMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  // This mutation declares a dependency on the faction
  // into which this ship is to be introduced.
  static fragments = {
    faction: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Faction { id }`,
  };
  // Introducing a ship will add it to a faction's fleet, so we
  // specify the faction's ships connection as part of the fat query.
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on IntroduceShipPayload {
        faction { ships },
        newShipEdge,
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_ADD',
      parentName: 'faction',
      parentID: this.props.faction.id,
      connectionName: 'ships',
      edgeName: 'newShipEdge',
      rangeBehaviors: {
        // When the ships connection is not under the influence
        // of any call, append the ship to the end of the connection
        '': 'append',
        // Prepend the ship, wherever the connection is sorted by age
        'orderby(newest)': 'prepend',
      },
    }];
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

If the parent is as obvious as faction, this is a piece of cake, but I've been having hard time identifying parentName and parentID if it came directly from query connections.

How do I do this?

Edit:

This is how query was exported.

```js
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    node: nodeField,
    viewer: {
      type: viewerType,
      resolve: () => ({}),
    },
    connections: {
      type: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Connections',
```

which in return is used in the relay container

```
export default Relay.createContainer(MakeRequestPage, {
    fragments: {
        connections: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on Connections {
```

Comment: Is `connections` in your query a GraphQL object or connection?

Comment: @AhmadFerdousBinAlam I have added the snippet below. The 'Connections' GraphQLObjectType comes with fields that are connection fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been having hard time identifying parentName and parentID *if it
>   came directly from query connections.*

`faction` and `ships` in the example from Relay documentation are exactly the same as `connections` and `drafts` in your case. Each `GraphQLObject` has an ID,so does your `connections` object. Therefore, for your mutation,  `parentName` is `connctions` and `parentID` is the ID of `connections`.

```
query {
    connections {
        id
        drafts(first: 10) {
            edges {
                node {
                    ... on Draft {
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I guess`connections` and `drafts` are terms from your application domain. Otherwise, `connections` confuses with GraphQL connection type.

Comment: `drafts` is definitely application domain term for the sake of example. I just realized `connections`, which I treated as commonly used root query like `node` or `viewer`, is also unique to our application. (My teammate came up with it). So I guess connections id should be like a global id.

Comment: Yes, the ID is a global ID.

Comment: What is parentName and parentId if you would have drafts directly under query?